# Unknown Label Type: Continuous -- with RandomForestClassifier

Tags: python, python-3.x, scikit-learn, random-forest

I have a dataframe with just a few fields.  I am trying to run a RandomForestClassifier over this dataframe, like this.

```
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
features = np.array(['INTEREST','SPREAD','BENCHMARK','BID','ASK','BVAL_G_SPREAD_BID','Z_SPRD_','DUR'])
clf = RandomForestClassifier()
clf.fit(df[features], df1['PRICE'])
```

When I try to run that, I get this error.

```
ValueError: Unknown label type: 'continuous'
```

All data types are: non-null float64

I'm using the code sample from the link below.

http://blog.yhat.com/tutorials/5-Feature-Engineering.html

df[features] is [242584 rows x 9 columns].  Maybe the dataset is too large?  Could that be the issue?

Comment: Price is a continuous column. RandomForest is a classifier so it needs a finite set of classes like 0 or 1. In case of a binary classifier you would want to predict whether your label will be 0 or 1. Here I am assuming 'Price' is just any valid number. You can't classify that; you can 'Predict' it. Perhaps you want to bin your Price column into something  like "<100", "<200" etc... and the [bins](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23.4/generated/pandas.cut.html) will be finite

Comment: Ah, go it. OK. Thanks!